# How to return an int value in C?

Tags: c, function, int, return

I am new to **C** language and trying to create a simple program to return name and age. I created a working function for returning the name but this does not work for returning the int.

The code I have now is:

```
int * GetAge(){  
  int Age;

  printf("What is your age: ");
  scanf(" %d", &Age);

  int * returnedage = Age;

  return returnedage;
}
```

This is GetName():

```
char * GetName(){
  char Name[31];

  printf("What is your name: ");
  scanf("%s", Name);

  char * returnedname = Name;

  return returnedname;
}
```

The warning is on this line:

```
int * returnedage = Age;
```

It says:

```
incompatible integer to pointer conversion
initializing 'int *' with an expression of type 'int'; take
the address with &
```

I have tried:

```
int * returnedage * Age;
int * returnedage & Age;
//for strcpy I set the function as a char
char * returnedage;
strcpy(Age, returnedage);
```

None of these work.

I want to just get the name and age then in main I am printing the name and age with:

```
printf("Your name is %s and your age is %d", GetName(), *GetAge());
```

This does not have any errors.

So my expected Output is:

```
What is your name: Ethan
What is your age: 13
Your name is Ethan and your age is 13
```

What I actually get is:

```
What is your name: ethan
What is your age: 13
exit status -1
```

Please tell me if there is a basic solution for this.

Comment: With your other "name" function, make sure you aren't returning a pointer to a local variable. You need to use `malloc` if you're going to return a pointer unless you're modifying a lojter that was passed in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
int GetAge()
{  
  int Age;

  printf("What is your age: ");
  scanf(" %d", &Age);

  return Age;
}
```

On main (Remove the * on the GetAge()):

```
printf("Your name is %s and your age is %d", GetName(), GetAge());
```

You have overcomplicated things. Read again the sources you are using to learn C to understand better what is going on.

**Edited:**
 Change your GetName() to:

```
void GetName(char *name){

  printf("What is your name: ");
  scanf("%s", name);
}
```

Now on main:

```
char name[31];
GetName(name);
printf("Your name is %s and your age is %d", name, GetAge());
```

The reason for that is that C can not return an array of characters (this is what you are trying to accomplish somehow). Instead, you can give that function the memory address of a local variable which lives in main() and store the user's input into that variable.

Comment: can you explain the necessity of the space before "%d" and why you do not removed it ? What happens if the user enter "aze" rather than a valid integer ?

Comment: Never use the conversion specifier `%s` without specifying a `WIDTH` to limit the number of characters that get written to the corresponding parameter!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
int GetAge()
{ 
    int Age;
    printf("What is your age: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &Age) != 1)
        return -1;  // return an error code if an integer couldn't be read
    return Age;
}
```

Now call the function using `GetAge()`.